# Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous codigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

this is my table structure.
tbl_user:
companyname,name,email.
tbl_userinfo:
phone,address,area,state,city,description.
tbl_category:
category_id,name.
i am joining three tables here is my model

```
$this->db->select(array('name', 'companyname','phone','address','email','state','city','pincode','area','description','image', 'c.name AS categoryname'));
        $this->db->from('tbl_user');
        $this->db->join('tbl_userinfo', 'tbl_userinfo.user_id = tbl_user.user_id');
        $this->db->join ('tbl_category', 'tbl_category.category_id = tbl_userinfo.service_category');
        $this->db->group_by(array('name', 'companyname', 'phone', 'address', 'email','state','city','pincode','area','description','image','categoryname')); 
        //$this->db->order_by('tbl_category.category_id');
        $this->db->where(array('tbl_user.user_id' => 16));
```

i wanted third column name as well but i m getting Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous codigniter

another code that i did use but it wont show me any values for joining of two table.

```
$this->db->select(array('tbl_user.name', 'tbl_user.companyname','tbl_userinfo.phone','tbl_userinfo.address','tbl_user.email','tbl_userinfo.state','tbl_userinfo.city','tbl_userinfo.pincode','tbl_userinfo.area','tbl_userinfo.description','tbl_userinfo.image', 'tbl_category.name'));
        $this->db->from('tbl_user');
        $this->db->join('tbl_userinfo', 'tbl_userinfo.user_id = tbl_user.user_id');
        $this->db->join ('tbl_category', 'tbl_userinfo.service_category = tbl_category.category_id');
        $this->db->group_by(array('tbl_user.name', 'tbl_user.companyname','tbl_userinfo.phone','tbl_userinfo.address','tbl_user.email','tbl_userinfo.state','tbl_userinfo.city','tbl_userinfo.pincode','tbl_userinfo.area','tbl_userinfo.description','tbl_userinfo.image', 'tbl_category.name'));
        $this->db->where(array('tbl_user.user_id' => 16));
```

Comment: use name column again with different alias

Comment: i have three tables and i m getting different column values and merge them but two table has same "name" column so it gets conflict see my second join query here it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comes with my own code.

```
$this->db->select(array('u.name', 'u.companyname','i.phone','i.address','u.email','i.state','i.city','i.pincode','i.area','i.description','i.image', 'c.name AS categoryname'));
        $this->db->from('tbl_user as u');
        $this->db->join('tbl_userinfo as i', 'i.user_id = i.user_id');
        $this->db->join ('tbl_category as c', 'c.category_id = i.service_category');
        $this->db->group_by(array('u.user_id')); 
        $this->db->where(array('u.group_id' => 16));        
        $query = $this->db->get ();
        return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because two of your tables both have a 'name' column. I would suggest explicitly selecting the column by using [table name].[column].

```
$result = $this->db->query('past your query here after checking it in an sql browser');
```

Comment: Can I suggest NOT using the ActiveRecord methods for this type of thing. I would just use the $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE') method and pasting your function in there so you can get some more control of column aliases etc.

Comment: can you put that code in answer so i can cross check .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $user_id = '16';
 $query = $this->db->select('tbl_user.companyname, tbl_user.name as UserName, tbl_user.email, tbl_userinfo.phone, tbl_userinfo.address, tbl_userinfo.area, tbl_userinfo.state, tbl_userinfo.city, tbl_userinfo.description, tbl_category.category_id, tbl_category.name as CategoryName')
                    ->from('tbl_user')
                    ->join('tbl_userinfo', 'tbl_userinfo.user_id = tbl_user.user_id')
                    ->join ('tbl_category', 'tbl_category.category_id = tbl_userinfo.service_category')
                    ->where('tbl_user.user_id', $user_id)
                    ->group_by('tbl_user.companyname')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
```

You can replate `'tbl_user.*'` with the columns names you want to get from that table, example: `'tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.name as UName, tbl_category.name as CName'` change the name of column if you have 2 or more columns with the same name in diferent tables you are joining, it will create always an ambiguous error because there are 2 columns with the same name and codeigniter doesn't know which one you want, if you want both you need to rename the both columns.

Also add the join to left because if there is no user_id or category_id it will not display you the result.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: this is not returning me NAME and PHONE field Column

Comment: can you please give us a printscreen or the structure of your tables ? based on what you posted i created an example, is normal that CI will return you an ambiguous if you have the column "name" or "phone" on the 3 tables. The idea is that i don't know from what table are you requesting name, phone, email, etc.. thats because is importatn to know the structure of database. Thx

Comment: edited in question please check first line of question. inserted all table values i need.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check and adapt to your needs !

Comment: it is not showing me any data now. i did try this way if you can check my another tried way portion a bit differ then yours. it should return some values still no values are there in view.

Comment: No problem, the idea is that if you don;t provide us enough information we cannot help you, you give information partially, also is good to know why you are grouping by all columns names, all columns need to be unique? or is enough if you group by user_id or companyname?

Comment: I have edited my question if you made a var_dump($query) it will show the data or error.

Comment: actually this is my first attempt for doing join of three table i have never done this before. i did mention all the information that i have with me sir.

Comment: yes i did tried it page loads fine but no values overthere.

Comment: i just copy pasted new code you put and it shows no table selected....SELECT *....

Comment: data = array('title' =>'homepage', 'main_content' =>'home_v');